# Read a CSV file in UTF-8 format

Tags: java, csv, utf-8

I am reading a csv file in java, adding a new column with new information and exporting it back to a CSV file. I have a problem in reading the CSV file in UTF-8 format. I read line by line and store it in a `StringBuilder`, but when I print the line I can see that the information I'm reading is not in UTF-8 but in ANSI. I used both `System.out.print` and `printstream` in UTF and the information appears still in ANSI. This is my code :

```
    BufferedReader br;
    try {
        br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(
                "./users.csv"), "UTF8"));
        String line;
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            if (line.contains("none@none.com")) {
                continue;
            }
            if (!line.contains("@") && !line.contains("FirstName")) {
                continue;
            }
            PrintStream ps = new PrintStream(System.out, true, "UTF-8");
            ps.print(line + "\n");
            sbusers.append(line);
            sbusers.append("\n");
            sbusers2.append(line);
            sbusers2.append(",");
        }
        br.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("Failed to read users file.");
    } finally {
    }
```

It prints out information like "Professor -P�s". Since the reading isn't being done correctly the output to the new file is also being exported in ANSI.

Answer (score 4):

Are you sure your CSV is `UTF-8` encoded? My guess is that it's not. Try using `ISO-8859-1` for reading the file, but keep the output as `UTF-8`. (`UTF8` and `UTF-8` both tend to work, but you should use `UTF-8` as @Marcelo suggested)

Answer (score 1):

In the line:

```
br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream("./users.csv"),"UTF8"));
```

Your charset should be `"UTF-8"` not `"UTF8"`.

Comment: Are you sure your file comes in UTF-8, can you open it in an enabled editor? In Windows, you can use Notepad++ to see what the source's file format is.

Comment: I checked the source with excel and notepad++ and it shows the source is in UTF-8.

Answer (score 1):

Printing to System.out using UTF encoding ????????????

Why would you do that ?  System.out and the encoding it uses is determined at the OS level (it becomes the default charset in the JVM), and that's the only one you want to use on System.out.

Comment: I used an excerpt of code posted in this site, to print UTF-8. I only needed to see what was being read in the file. Still, the printing is not the problem, the reading of the file is not working.

Comment: How exactly do you know that for sure ?

Comment: Because I am opening the resulting CSV and is being printed out in ANSI. I posted a question about 10 minutes ago with a writing problem but I came to realize it was the reading all along.

Comment: And you are opening the resulting CSV with what exactly ?  And which binary-bits-to-displayed-characters happens in that other software that you are "opening the resulting CSV with" ?

Answer (score 1):

Fist, as suggested by @Marcelo, use `UTF8` instead of `UTF-8`:

```
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
       new InputStreamReader(
                  new FileInputStream("./users.csv"), "UTF8"));
```

Second, forget about the `PrintStream`, just use `System.out`, or better yet, a logging API. You don't need to worry about how Java will output your string to the console (number one rule about character encoding: After you've read things successfully, let Java handle the encoding and only worry about it again when you are writing to an external file / database / etc).

Third and more important, check that your file is really encoded in UTF-8, this is the cause of 99% of the encoding problems.

Make sure that you test with a real UTF-8 file (use tools like iconv to convert to UTF-8 and be sure about it).

Answer (score 0):

found a potential solution(I had the same problem). Depending on the type of UTF-8 encoding you need to specify if further...

Replace:

```
br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(
            "./users.csv"), "UTF8"));
```

With:

```
br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(
            "./users.csv"), "ISO_8859_1"));
```

For further understanding: https://mincong.io/2019/04/07/understanding-iso-8859-1-and-utf-8/